# Error compiling gold in binutils

Tags: linker, binutils

I am trying to compile the project KernelGen (http://hpcforge.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/kernelgen/index.php/Compiling) for some research project I am doing , the build script is using rpmbuild and it looks like it has a dependency on gold from binutils. Build keeps failing when trying to compile gold with the following error:

```
/bin/sh ./../ylwrap yyscript.y y.tab.c yyscript.c y.tab.h yyscript.h y.output yyscript.output -- byacc  -d
byacc: e - line 42 of "/home/xxx/rpmbuild/BUILD/binutils-2.23.2/gold/yyscript.y", syntax error
%pure-parser
^
```

The file yyscript.c looks like this:

```
/* We need to use a pure parser because we might be multi-threaded.
   We pass some arguments through the parser to the lexer.  */

%pure-parser
%parse-param {void* closure}
%lex-param {void* closure}

/* Since we require bison anyhow, we take advantage of it.  */
%error-verbose

/* The values associated with tokens.  */
```

It looks like it is some kind of grammar file that fails to parse. Things is this file is from the binutils package itself and I can't find a reason why it is failing to parse.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of byacc doesn't properly support %pure-parser, which I believe was originally a bison extension.  Use bison instead.